# Error Springboot haciendo peticion Post con encabezado Content-Type 'multipart/form-data'

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, post

Estoy en java con SpringBoot, queriendo hacer una ruta donde se sube o crea un producto con su información correspondiente:

```
@PostMapping(value = "", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper<RespuestaProductoDTO>> crearProducto(
        @RequestBody @Valid CrearProductoDTO datos,
        UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder
    ){
        Producto producto = productoService.crear(datos);
        URI uri = uriComponentsBuilder.path("producto/{id}").buildAndExpand(producto.getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(new ResponseWrapper<RespuestaProductoDTO>(
            HttpStatus.CREATED, 
            "Producto creado con éxito", 
            new RespuestaProductoDTO(producto), 
            null));
    }
```

donde el dto tiene dentro otro Dto que se llama CrearVersionDTO y ese contiene la imagen: MultiparFile imagen:

```
package com.products.dto.version;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.DecimalMin;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Min;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern;

public record CrearVersionDTO(
    @NotBlank(message = "El nombre de la versión es requerido")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ0-9\\s]{4,50}$", message = "El nombre de la versión debe tener entre 4 y 50 caracteres")
    String nombre,
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ0-9\\s\\-\\_\\.\\(\\)\\¿\\?\\¡\\!]{15,2000}$", message = "La descripción debe tener entre 15 y 2000 caracteres")
    String descripcion,

    @NotNull(message = "El precio es requerido")
    @DecimalMin(value = "0.01", message = "El precio debe ser mayor que 0")
    BigDecimal precio,

    @DecimalMin(value = "0", message = "El precio de descuento debe ser positivo")
    BigDecimal precioDescuento,
    Boolean estado,

    @Min(value = 1, message = "La cantidad de stock mínima es 1")
    Integer stock,

    @NotNull(message = "Una imagen de versión es requerido")
    MultipartFile imagen
) {
    
}
```

pero cuando hago la petición (en thunder de Visual Studio Code) el servidor me laza error 415 y en la consola imprime esto:

```
2024-02-15T09:17:56.815-03:00  WARN 2960 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------793561112738948536444025;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]
```

luego le agrego esto al encabezado de la petición: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary_value`

y me lanza el mismo error

```
2024-02-15T09:17:09.540-03:00  WARN 2960 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=boundary_value;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]
```

Por favor alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal? (nunca hice una peticion con archivos)

Comment: ¿Que pasa si cambias @RequestBody y le pones @ModelAttribute?